# Is it possible to change the Values of a NumberAxis in JavaFX 2.0?

Tags: java, charts, javafx-2, javafx

I'm not sure if this is even possible. But basically I want to change the values of a `NumberAxis` in JavaFX to Strings.

```
final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 40, 1);
```

So what I now want to change is the numbers 0 - 40 to any String.

Another Question is. I have added `Regions` to my `Chart` so it displays 'Bars' on specific values. Whenever I change the 'Startvalue' of my xAxis to any higher than '0', the Bars randomly disappear. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You can provide your own values using `setTickLabelFormatter` method. See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/ValueAxis.html#setTickLabelFormatter(javafx.util.StringConverter)

P.S.: please ask 2nd question separately and provide code sample

Comment: Hi, thanks. But I think i need some more help. I simply want to add the String ':00' after all values on my X-AXIS (NumberAxis). If i do it like this:        `final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 13, 1);
   
        xAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(xAxis)
        {
            @Override
            public String toString(Number object)
            {
                return String.format(":00", object);  
            }
        });`
all my values are replaced with ':00' which is not the behaviour i want. Thanks for any more help on this.

Comment: `String.format("%1$s:00", object)` -- more details about formatting here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 1):

Use a [CategoryAxis](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/CategoryAxis.html) instead of a [NumberAxis](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html) (or follow the tickLabelFormatter solution in Sergey's answer).