# Is there a way to get access on the values of a NumberAxis() in JavaFX 2.0 ?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I want to access on every specific value of my X-AXIS which is a NumberAxis in JavaFX.
Let's say i got `new NumberAxis(0, 10, i)` and i want to remove the Ticks 8 - 10;

I thought about something like `xAxis.getTickValues().get(8).remove();` `xAxis.getTickValues().get(9).remove();` `xAxis.getTickValues().get(10).remove();`

What is the correct method to get access on my Tickvalues?

Comment: This question is pretty similar to [Is it possible to change the Values of a NumberAxis in JavaFX 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399667/is-it-possible-to-change-the-values-of-a-numberaxis-in-javafx-2-0)

Comment: no, it's different. i think i'm not clear enough somehow. xD To change the values we've used a TickLabelFormatter which is fine. But i need to get access on the single values to remove them for example. I'm not sure if this is even possible because there is no method for it. If we can use ticklabelformatter for that as well, i have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the labels by overriding the DefaultFormatter

```
    xAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(xAxis) {
        @Override
        public String toString(Number number) {
            return (number.intValue() > 7) ? "" :  String.format("%2.0f", number);
        }
    });
```